# TypeError in Decimal module: integer argument expected, got float

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu-14.04

I am quite new to the Python language, and for my first exercise I wanted to make a script that calculates the constant e. 
To do this, I defined a function `calc_temp` which would have a variable `temp` and temp would start off equal to one. I would then multiply `temp` by the quotient of 1 and a variable called `e_num` I would then add temp to a variable `approx_e`. 
Then, I used a `while True:` loop to perform the function indefinitely.
The code looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import math
from decimal import *
temp = 1
approx_e = Decimal(1)
e_num = 1
def calc_temp(e_num):
    global approx_e
    global temp
    len_ = math.log10(math.factorial(e_num))
    getcontext().prec = len_
    temp = Decimal(temp * 1 / e_num)
    e_num = e_num + 1
    approx_e = approx_e + temp
    return approx_e 
while True:
    calc_temp(e_num)
```

However, when I execute the script, it raises the following `TypeError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dorian/Desktop/ever3.py", line 17, in <module>
    calc_temp(e_num)
   File "/home/dorian/Desktop/ever3.py", line 14, in calc_temp
    approx_e = approx_e + temp
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/decimal.py", line 1209, in __add__
    ans = ans._fix(context)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/decimal.py", line 1692, in _fix
    changed = rounding_method(self, digits)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/decimal.py", line 1771, in _round_half_even
    if _exact_half(self._int, prec) and \
TypeError: integer argument expected, got float
```

I tried changing the type of the variables, making them `Decimal`s, `int`egers, and `float`ing point numbers, but it still raises the error. What could be causing it?

Comment: Why are you using Decimal there in the first place?

Comment: e is an irrational number, so I used `Decimal` because it can store large values and is more precise than `float`. The variable `len_` is there to determine how precise the `Decimal` function will need to be so it can calculate accurately.

Comment: if len_ is 0.99 should precision be 1 or 0?

Comment: It should be 1. len_ is the amount of digits contained in 1/n!. I used this function to make the precision of the `Decimal`s only as precise as it needs to be, so the script doesn't take a long time to execute.

Comment: @JohnThomson, I asked as `int(0.99)` will be `0`

Comment: I am aware of this. To counter this I used `int(round(len_))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the context precision to a float:

```
len_ = math.log10(math.factorial(e_num))
getcontext().prec = len_
```

Set it to an integer:

```
getcontext().prec = int(len_)
```

Quoting the [`decimal.Context()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#decimal.Context):

> The *prec* field is a positive integer that sets the precision for arithmetic operations in the context.

Comment: Why did the Traceback say the error was in `approx_e + temp` instead of `getcontext().prec = len_`?

Comment: @JohnThomson: because the precicion is only consulted by that time to produce a result within the given precision.

Comment: @JohnThomson: did you mean to accept then unaccept again? Anything missing still?

Comment: I was waiting for more answers, but I might as well.